# NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpBackend

Tags: angular15, angular-standalone-components

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yWLs.png) error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeDun.png) main.ts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1xUv.png) app-config-service.ts

after i replaced  bootstrapModule with bootstrapApplication in main.js and moved all providers in app-module to main.ts. i got this error.

Comment: Do not put screen shot of your code, please write it down.

Answer (score 1):

Add provideHttpClient() in your main.ts providers.

```
 providers: [
  provideHttpClient(),
  { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, ... }
],
```